# CentOS VNC-Server

Tags: centos, vnc

Are there any instructions how to install a VNC-Server on CentOS? Some of them explain how to setup a terminal server, but I primarily want to use the currently logged in desktop.

Comment: Did you search anywhere, this topic is very easy to find information on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link for detail [instruction on how to install a VNC-Server](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server)

Summary:

```
     yum install vnc-server
```

if you windows manager is not already installed then :

```
     yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop Environment"
```

Start vncserver serivce

```
     /sbin/service vncserver start
```

configure your ~/.vnc/xstartup file according to your preference of desktop settings:

to start vnc session :
         vncserver

connect a vnc viewer by pointing to the session ID you received when start the vnc session

Comment: Well, I've found this instruction, but unfortunately it's not working. I've copied the configuration and logfiles to http://pastebin.com/BXe5KcWn. When started as root, I get a new desktop, not the one currently shown on my real display. When run as chris, I just see a blank X11 screen with cursor without window manager.

Comment: I didn't read the article until the end. It's working now. Thank you.

Comment: you might have configured ~/.vnc/xstartup to resolve your black X11 screen issue. I will update this in the summary as well